# For Twitter , how to create test user accounts?

Tags: testing, twitter, user-accounts

Facebook allows you to create test user accounts that can only be used for testing purpose.

Does Twitter provide similar functionality ? I don't want to get my application blacklisted for creating fake user accounts; do I have to use my real user account for testing my application ? What strategies are your using for testing application with Twitter ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As far as I know, there is nothing in Twitter's rules against creating account (unlike Facebook, where with the exception of test accounts, you're not allowed to create multiple accounts for testing purposes). So, you can just register the account like you normally would.

You might want to take a look at [this post](http://www.ragorder.com/twitter-test-account-testing-the-twitter-api-with-a-temporary-account/) for some other tips for test accounts (hiding your tweets, deleting the account when you're done testing, etc.).

Comment: Keep their terms in mind, they have been increasingly stingy. For instance, this could be an example of account squatting and get you banned. This happened at our company on many occasions. The real trick is spoofing phone numbers where possible due to their outdated verification system.

Comment: I can confirm that this seems to be outdated. Creating fake twitter accounts for testing causes the account to be locked rather quickly (in my case, it didn't even take 10 minutes), especially if DEAs are used.

Answer (score 14):

*I'm currently creating a Twitter application and here are some of the strategies I'm using.*

- I create my accounts in combination with Gmail addresses. If I create a gmail account as user `bob@gmail.com` , I secure the Twitter name `@bob` on Twitter. That way it's kind of hard to forget where to email a lost password. I don't go crazy, as I don't need 100's of test accounts but I do have up to three.
- I log on to my test accounts using Chrome because it will automatically recall your password as soon as you type in your Twitter name on the home page. That way it is easy to switch between them, but note that I find it hard sometimes to know which account is actually active because I'm constantly looking at other profiles. This gets confusing if I don't constantly look at the logged in user icon indicator.
- **Never, ever re-tweet anything unless you absolutely have to for a test case** or use hash-tags unless for a test case. Unbelievably even on a completely un-publicized account, I had a few surprise Twitter users in my DB a few seconds after I re-tweeted a link.
- on Localhost, **close all your other browser windows** while your testing. Especially if your calling the API through AJAX. You never know which sites you have open whom also call the Twitter API through AJAX, and this can seriously screw with your tests and rate limits. Especially when your developing live.
- I would **not recommend** protecting your tweets. It's too limiting for *most* use cases.
- For my site, I need to place a link in the tweets. Twitter will not
  allow live links to `http://localhost` so you have to plan around
  this and have a live test server sooner then you may anticipate.

Answer (score 9):

Twitter has one of the easiest registration processes I have seen.  You can quite easily create several test accounts; this is the only method I have used.

Here is a [blog post](http://www.ragorder.com/twitter-test-account-testing-the-twitter-api-with-a-temporary-account/) about it.